# Backキーでアプリを終了させたいです

Tags: javascript, android, monaca, cordova

monacaでandroidアプリを開発しています。
アプリの動きでよくあるような
backキー(戻るボタン)を押す→
ダイアログ表示→「終了しますか？」「キャンセル」

- 終了しますかを押すとアプリ終了
- キャンセルを押すとアプリに戻る

のような形にしたいと考えているのですが・・・

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackPressed, false);

function onBackPressed(){
    confirmExit()
}

function confirmCallback(id){
    if(1 == id){
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
}

function confirmExit(){
    navigator.notification.confirm("アプリケーションを終了しますか？",  confirmCallback, "終了メニュー", "終了,キャンセル")
}
```

上記のコードで理想通りの形になったのですが、いざアプリをビルドすると全く動きません。
何が悪いのでしょうか？

初心者のため解決方法をコードにて教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたしますm(__)m

---

Myakuさんにご指摘いただいた通り以下のコードでやってみましたがやはりダメでした。 
ビルドする前（デバッカー上）は、戻るを押すとダイアログが表示され、終了を押せば終了、キャンセルでダイアログが消えるのですが、ビルド後は戻るを押してもダイアログが表示されず、また戻ることもできなくなる→戻るボタンが機能しなくなる状態です。 
`index.html`含め、全3ページで構成しているのですが、全ページで戻るボタンが効かなくなります。 
その他は特に異常はありません。エラーも出ていない状態です。 
ページ内容に問題があるのかと思い、リンク用ボタンのみ配置してみましたが、やはりビルド後は戻るボタンが効かなくなる状態です。 
どうぞよろしくお願いしますm(__)m

```
document.addEventListener(
    "deviceready", 
    function(){
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackPressed, false);
    }, 
    false
); 
function onBackPressed(){ confirmExit(); } 
function confirmCallback(id){
    if(1 == id){ navigator.app.exitApp(); }
} 
function confirmExit(){ 
    navigator.notification.confirm(
        "アプリケーションを終了しますか？", 
        confirmCallback, 
        "終了メニュー", 
        "終了,キャンセル"
    );
}
```

Comment: 冒頭の "ocument" は document のコピペミスだと思いますが、念の為確認して下さい。質問は「編集」で修正できます。コードを綺麗に表示させる方法は、http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068 などを参考にして下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deviceready`後にEventListenerを登録していますか？

```
document.addEventListener(
    "deviceready", 
    function(){document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackPressed, false);},
    false
);
```

また、

> いざアプリをビルドすると全く動きません。

と言った質問ですと現象が理解しがたいです。
全く動かないとは

- ビルドができない
- アプリを起動できない
- バックボタンを押した際に意図しない動作をする
- バックボタンを押した際にページが戻る
- バックボタンを押しても反応が無い

など詳しく回答ができるはずです。
また、起動時なのか遷移後なのかでバックボタンの挙動も変わるので
`index.html`か否かも参考情報になります。
エラーが出ている場合はエラーの内容を詳しく添付してください。

---

**追記**
・ビルドした後のみ動作しない。
・戻るボタン押下時にダイアログが出ない
の追加情報を受け考えたところ
`navigator.notification`のプラグインを追加していない可能性があります。

`設定`>`Cordovaプラグインの管理`>`Notification (org.apache.cordova.dialogs)`

以上を有効にしてください。

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。
ご指摘いただいた通り
以下のコードでやってみましたが
やはりダメでした。


ビルドする前（デバッカー上）は、
戻るを押すとダイアログが表示され
終了を押せば終了、キャンセルでダイアログが消えるのですが
ビルド後は戻るを押してもダイアログが表示されず
また戻ることもできなくなる→戻るボタンが機能しなくなる状態です。

index.html含め全3ページで構成しているのですが
全ページで戻るボタンが効かなくなります。

その他は特に異常はありません。
エラーも出ていない状態です。

ページ内容に問題があるのかと思い
リンク用ボタンのみ配置してみましたが
やはりビルド後は戻るボタンが効かなくなる状態です。


どうぞよろしくお願いしますm(__)m

Comment: document.addEventListener(
    "deviceready", 
    function(){document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackPressed, false);},
    false
);

function onBackPressed(){
    confirmExit()
}

function confirmCallback(id){
    if(1 == id){
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
}

function confirmExit(){
    navigator.notification.confirm("アプリケーションを終了しますか？",  confirmCallback, "終了メニュー", "終了,キャンセル")
}


コードはこちらになります。
見てみてくださいm(__)m

Comment: 情報は質問文を編集する形で追記してください。コメント欄ですと見づらい上に情報が埋もれてしまうので……

Comment: 追記いたしました。ご確認ください。

Comment: Myakuさん

プラグインを追加したところ
ビルド後も動作するようになりました！

ご丁寧にご回答いただき
どうもありがとうございましたm(__)m

Comment: @take 解決できたのであれば、是非、[回答の承認](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)をお願いします。他の方が解決方法を見つけやすくなると思うので。